# Creating a virtual interface to always access a DHCPed interface with the same ip

Tags: networking, iptables, dhcp, bridge

I have an interface that on connect always gets a new IP.
So I want to create a virtual interface with a static IP that "relays" everything over the physical interface.
This would be useful to bind applications to the virtual interface that do not support binding to an interface name.
I imagine this being possible with ethernet bridges and/or iptables but I do not really have a clue.

*edit:* A network alias is not an option because I can only use the provided IP.

Comment: Can you not just statically assign the same IP to the MAC address for this system so that DHCP always gives it the same IP? That's what I do.

Comment: What services are you using that you need to supply the full IP:port socket address?  Usually you can just have the service listen on any address at a particular port.  You could perform masquerading with iptables but the clients would still need to know the appropriate IP address to use to reach you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an IP tunnel (encrypted or non-encrypted). The problem is: You need an endpoint for this tunnel. Maybe this is possible with local addresses, too. Probably difficult with normal IP tunnels but it should work with two instances of OpenVPN, creating e.g. `tun0` and `tun1`. Your applications could bind to one of them then and would always see the same IP address.